# What might be causing anchor to stick out of div or list

Tags: html, css

I have problem with list tags which might be more than one line and also has must be anchor.
Does anybody know what is it with anchor that makes them very hard to design?

[image: d]

I will drop a little bit of the html and css here, in case you recognise something

```
<div class="tagsList">
     <ul>
         <a href="linksmth"><li><span class="tagSpan">Tag name here</span></li></a>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And than I have this css:

```
span.tagSpan {
background: #e7ebee;
padding: 5px 10px;
float: left;
}
```

I tried around here and there but couldn't find anything relevant. What can be the issue?

Comment: Use anchor (a) inside li

Comment: Hm it actually worked :D that was probably the only thing I didn't try, I tried putting in divs, removing list and stuff. Btw I'm having hard time with giving margin directly to the anchor

Comment: Try giving margin to li instead of anchor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a `ul` tag should contain `li` only,

Therefore the *initial* value of `<a>` `display` is `inline` so if you change it to `display: inline-block` you could easily control the `margin` and other stuff.

```css
span.tagSpan {
  background: #e7ebee;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.with-margin {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagsList">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="linksmth"><span class="tagSpan">Tag name here</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

<a class="with-margin" href="linksmth"><span class="tagSpan">Tag name here</span></a>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)